# how can i link the properties from my ontology to synonyms

Tags: jena, ontology, synset

i made an ontology and i want to link the properties to synonyms so that when i query it by sparql i can get result
for example when i query:

```
        "SELECT * WHERE{ " 
             +"{?x rdfs:subClassOf ?y." 
             +"?y owl:onProperty mine:concerned;"
             +"owl:someValuesFrom mine:createObject.}"
```

i see the result i want but i want to see the result when i use of the synonyms property.for example:

```
          "SELECT * WHERE{ " 
             +"{?x rdfs:subClassOf ?y." 
             +"?y owl:onProperty mine:focus;"
             +"owl:someValuesFrom mine:createObject.}"
```

Comment: If they are truly synonyms, you could use `owl:equivalentProperty` and make sure that the reasoner is active. Another option would `rdfs:subPropertyOf` when one property is narrower than the other.

Comment: i tried owl:equivalentProperty but i see no result. and i want to get the rdfs:subclass no property

Comment: Can you add a sample of your graph as well? Including examples of what you currently get and what you would like to get.